# How to create multiple excel files at the time using codeigniter

Tags: php

I was able to download excel with multiple sheet , How to download multiple excel file is it possible to download multiple excel file at the time?

```
<?php

public function getUserInfoExport(){

    $this->load->library('excel');
    $obj = new Excel();
    $startdate = '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
    $enddate = '2019-01-01 23:59:59';
    $count = $this->export_model->userDetailCount($startdate,$enddate); // Above 3lakhs datas
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $count) {
        // Add new sheet
        $objWorkSheet = $obj->createSheet($i);
        //Write Heading 
        $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('A1', 'USER_ID');
        $objWorkSheet->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('B1', 'USER_NAME');
        $objWorkSheet->getStyle('B1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('C1', 'EMAIL_ID');
        $objWorkSheet->getStyle('C1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('D1', 'CONTACT_NO');
        $objWorkSheet->getStyle('D1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        //Get records based under condition           
        $offset =  ($i == 0) ? '0' : ($i*EXCEL_LIMIT+1);
        $val = $this->export_model->userDetail($startdate,$enddate,$offset);
        $row = 2;
        foreach($val as $value) {
            $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('A'.$row, $value->USER_ID);
            $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('B'.$row, $value->USERNAME);
            $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('C'.$row, $value->EMAIL_ID);
            $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('D'.$row, $value->CONTACT_NO);
            $row++;
        }

        $page = $i+1;
        $objWorkSheet->setTitle("UserInfo$page");//Title Of the Sheet
        $i++;

    }
     $filename='UserInfo.xlsx';
     header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
     header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');     
     $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($obj, 'Excel2007');
     $objWriter->save('php://output');
} ?>
```

Here i able to download 100k data only. how to possible for 300k data?

Comment: You can only do only one download at a time.
If you like to zip the files have a look at this.http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: @Jaykant this is not true, you can achieve this using  [PThread](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)